# Mongo Aggregation Pipeline $lookup with nested embedded documents and $project

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mgo

I have two collections `users` and `groups. Lets pretend that the collections have the following data in them currently.

The `users` collection has the following document

```
{  
   "_id":"57a944390b1acf0d069388c1",
   "first":"John",
   "last":"Smith",
   "email":"John.Smith@gmail.com",
   "groups":[  
      {  
         "id":"57aab09c0b1acf135a6b6856",
         "name":"Group A"
      },
      {  
         "id":"57aab0ed0b1acf135a6b6857",
         "name":"Group B"
      },
      {  
         "id":"57b008be31a5a202ee4ff47b",
         "name":"Group C"
      }
   ]
}
```

The `groups` collection has the following two documents

```
[  
   {  
      "_id":"57aab0ed0b1acf135a6b6857",
      "name":"Group B",
      "requests":[  
         {  
            "_id":"57b14b1831a5a2756fbc9873",
            "description":"Request A",
            "denied_requests":[ ]
         }
      ]
   }   {  
      "_id":"57b008be31a5a202ee4ff47b",
      "name":"Group C",
      "requests":[  
         {  
            "_id":"57b14c2131a5a2756fbc9874",
            "description":"Request B",
            "denied_requests":[ ]
         },
         {  
            "_id":"57b14e3131a5a2756fbc9875",
            "description":"Request C",
            "denied_requests":[  
               "57a944390b1acf0d069388c1"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

What I need to do is use the aggregation pipeline to query all requests for a user excluding requests that the user has denied.

I would imagine this would consist of the following *psudo* steps given the `user_id` as the input to the problem.

- `$match` on the user `_id` field
- `$project` the group `id`s from the result of previous step
- `$lookup` using the `id` from the `$project` on the `users.groups` on the `_id` of the `groups` collection
- `$match` on `requests` that dont have current user id in `denied_requests` array on request.

*Sample Input*

Sample input to this would be `57a944390b1acf0d069388c1` representing the users `_id`

*Sample Output*

Sample output to this would be the following list of requests that the user has not denied.

```
[
       {  
          "_id":"57b14b1831a5a2756fbc9873",
          "description":"Request A",
          "denied_requests":[]
       },
       {  
          "_id":"57b14c2131a5a2756fbc9874",
          "description":"Request B",
          "denied_requests":[ ]
       }   
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following pipeline, it should give you the desired result:

```
var userId = "57a944390b1acf0d069388c1";
db.users.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": userId } },
    { "$unwind": "$groups" },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "groups",
            "localField": "groups.id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "group"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$group" },
    {
        "$project": {
            "requests": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$group.requests",
                    "as": "item",
                    "cond": { "$not": { 
                        "$setIsSubset": [ 
                            [userId], "$$item.denied_requests" 
                        ] 
                    } }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$requests" },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": "$requests._id",
            "description": "$requests.description",
            "denied_requests": "$requests.denied_requests"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I tried this and it looks like nothing is returned after the first `$lookup`

Comment: I just realized that the DB I was going agaisnt was < 3.2 which means $lookup wasn't supported and was failing silently.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7626 I believe covers this.